# Erro de referência Assembly no Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Tenho um projeto DDD no VS 2017 e Asp.Net MVC, usando o SDK 2.1.201. Eu formatei meu computador e instalei novamente o VS 2017 e o SDK 2.1.201... só que quando eu abro o projeto, dá erro de compilação em todas as camadas relacioano ao assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu chequei a instalação do SK e está tudo certo, mas não sei o que está dando errado....

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por favor, me ajudem!!! Não posso perder esse projeto :(

Comment: O mesmo problema que o seu só que o dele é ASP.NET Core 1.1 vê se te ajuda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169794/error-cs0234-the-type-or-namespace-name-aspnetcore-does-not-exist-in-the-name

Comment: Não funcionou @Netinho Santos... :(